# How to fix 'java.io.IOException: HTTP full-duplex channel timeout' while running jenkins cli?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am getting

`java.io.IOException: HTTP full-duplex channel timeout`

while running jenkins-cli command,

`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://mytestjenkins.com -noCertificateCheck -auth @/tmp/password-file who-am-i`

I have tried using ssh, and keystore, but it gives me the same result.

```
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

Jenkins 2.164.1

I saw similar question was asked 3 years ago with few answers, but no solution yet.

Any helps is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You need to disable proxy_buffering in your reverse proxy
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-users/NWg5L9qzduM/ut6ztSSkAwAJ
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43666?focusedCommentId=311367&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-311367
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47279

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23985293)

Comment: @Robert This isn't a link-only answer as, if you remove all the links, you get "You need to disable proxy_buffering in your reverse proxy" which appears to be an attempt to answer the question.